# how to set initial selection on listFragment

Tags: android, selection, android-listfragment

Is it possible to set the inital selection on a listFragment? I would like to show an event list temporally ordered with option to see past events if scrolling up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getListView().setSelection(position);
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29)